# ALAssetsLibrary getting the path of a video and play it later

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, alassetslibrary

Using below code I am able to get the video files in tableview. But I am unable to get the path to the video so that I would save it and use it later to play.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [activity startAnimating];

    assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    UIImage *viewImage;

    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){  
        if (error) {  
            NSLog(@"error");  
        } else {  
            NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);


        }  
    }];  


    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll  usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){

        if (group != NULL) {

            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){


                if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]) {
                    NSLog(@"asset: %@", result);
                    [assets addObject:result];
                }

            }];
        }

        [self.tableview reloadData];
        [self.activity stopAnimating];
        [self.activity setHidden:YES];

    }
           failureBlock:^(NSError *error){

                NSLog(@"failure"); }];

}


// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [assets count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    ALAsset *asset = [assets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video %d", indexPath.row+1]];

    return cell;
}
```

This is my output:

```
2012-07-19 12:37:42.135 mptest[17310:707] asset: ALAsset - Type:Video, URLs:{
    "com.apple.quicktime-movie" = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=336068EA-C1B1-481C-82DA-F2419561A91A&ext=MOV";
}
2012-07-19 12:37:42.147 mptest[17310:707] asset: ALAsset - Type:Video, URLs:{
    "com.apple.quicktime-movie" = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=A1CBDDE4-4BC1-48F2-84E0-028D7B7F4879&ext=MOV";
}
2012-07-19 12:37:42.156 mptest[17310:707] asset: ALAsset - Type:Video, URLs:{
    "com.apple.quicktime-movie" = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=3D76ABC7-515C-42E7-A940-B149C78FBAB6&ext=MOV";
}
2012-07-19 12:37:42.262 mptest[17310:707] error
```

Can anyone help me wih this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the actual file-path from the AssetsLibrary because of sandboxing. However, you have various options to access/play the video file.

1) Query the URL of the Asset using the `url` method of `ALAssetRepresentation` and pass it to an instance of MPMoviePlayerController to play the video. This url starts with assets-library:// and is not a file-system url, but `MPMoviePlayerController` knows how to handle such an URL.

2) Get the video contents by using the `getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:` of `ALAssetsRepresentation` to save the video to your own app sandbox to play/edit/share it or use `getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:` to stream the video contents.

Comment: Thanx, First option will not work. As I only want to get the path and save it so that I would play the video later. Dont want to play the video right after selecting it

And for the second option can you help me with any code snippet. I dont have muh experience in ALAssetsLibrary

Comment: If you plan to use MPMoviePlayerController in your application option 1) is still the way to go. As you can store the URL and then just use it later at any time. To implement option 2) take a look here; http://ios-dev-sajjeel.blogspot.de/2012/03/although-u-can-see-many-same-solutions.html

Comment: Yes, MPMoviePlayerController is a good option, I dont have any issue playing with it. How can i store the URL? If you could modify my above code.

Comment: You already save the asset objects as I see. So all you need to do is call [[assetObject representation] url] at the time you want to play the video.

Comment: Mr. Appdeveloper/Mr. holtmann, Please could u give me some details about I want to play video on MPMovieplayer using ALasset URL only or by 1 option . I tried but video not playing. (video is in ok formate.).