# Is there any way to get a photo' path in photoLibrary?

Tags: ios, filepath, assets, assetslibrary

first of all ,forgive my poor english.
this is the first time I post my question.

Question：
        I accessed the AssetsLibrary, got the assets(some pics),then I stored them into
        a NSArray, and now I want to know their file paths, such as "xx/xxx/xxxxxx.png"；

after read the help docs from apple, I can get some of it's properties, 
but the urls,such as:
   image:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=F2C5D63D-BCA9-4A53-ACA7-8FB9C6EDC1E6&ext=JPG
does not help.

Is there any way can help me doing this?
Great appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556100/alassetslibrary-getting-the-path-of-a-video-and-play-it-later/11556277#11556277) answer. It is about movie files, but applies to images as well.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll check it. Maybe I should do some work to parse the asset URL; seems that possible.  thx again.