# Acquiring absolute image file path using iOS Swift

Tags: postgresql, swift, http-post

> Does anyone know how to acquire the absolute path from an image using
>   iOS Swift? I am trying to send the file path in a HTTP post request. I
>   have tried the code below but it takes too long to process. I am trying
>   to send the file path of an image to a PostgreSQL database. Any tips
>   are greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

```
var paths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
   var documentDirectory: NSString = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as NSString
   var localFilePath: NSString = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("image.png")
   var data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
   data.writeToFile(localFilePath, atomically: true)
```

Comment: What is `image`? If the question is about the path to an image stored in the photo album, then you can't get its absolute path, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556100/alassetslibrary-getting-the-path-of-a-video-and-play-it-later or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121204/how-can-i-get-original-nsdata-of-uiimage.

Answer (score 0):

```
let documentsUrl = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL
if let fileAbsoluteUrl = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent( "image.png").absoluteURL {
    println(fileAbsoluteUrl)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Leonardo! I really appreciate your help and tips to become a stronger Swift programmer.