# How to get the path of an photo in camera roll or just taken ( iOS/Swift )?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-camera

This is an iOS/Swift app. I use Fusuma, a camera library, for getting access to camera, taking photos and display them. Neat and easy.

Then I get to the part where I want to upload photos to server by POSTing their paths(in camera roll, I suppose).

So how do I do that? I did some search, seems like no clear answer in Swift.

Code like:

```
class ReceiptSaveViewController: UIViewController, FusumaDelegate {

...

@IBOutlet weak var photo1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var photo2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var photo3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var photo4: UIImageView!

...

@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: SwiftyButton) {
        // Show Fusuma
        let fusuma = FusumaViewController()

        // fusumaCropImage = false

        fusuma.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(fusuma, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

...

// MARK: FusumaDelegate Protocol
    func fusumaImageSelected(image: UIImage) {

        print("Image selected")
        let photos = [photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4]
        //let btns = [btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4]
        for photo in photos {
            if photo.image == nil {
                photo.image = image
                //btns[photo.tag - 1].alpha = 1
                return
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: show us your source code...

Comment: when you take the image, it does not store a physical file onto your phone, but rather in an object you defined. You have to write this and store onto your phone instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can see this link [How can i get original nsdata of uiimage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121204/how-can-i-get-original-nsdata-of-uiimage). it use ALAssetsLibrary which has been replaced in swift ios 9 I think. see how to replace ALAssetsLibrary in ios 9 here [How to use PHPhotoLibrary like ALAssetsLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500266/how-to-use-phphotolibrary-like-alassetslibrary) ALAssets replaced by PHPhotoLibrary(Photo.framework) for ios 9.

or you can see the absolute URL of the image using this method [Acquiring absolute image file path using iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774401/acquiring-absolute-image-file-path-using-ios-swift) use the image represented by FusumaImageSelected.

correct me if I'm wrong.